# OpenIDM NullPointerException when installing Salesforce Identity Connect

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, salesforce, openidm

Would anyone know what to do about the following error I'm getting when trying to install Salesforce Identity Connect on a Win 2012 R2 server trial version? I'm using java 1.8.0_144

```
WARN Cannot release acquired trigger trigger-salesforceDataSyncNow in group scheduler-service-group, trigger has not been acquired [RepoJobStore]OpenIDM ready
Scheduled service "scheduler-service-group.salesforceDataSyncNow" invocation reported failure: 
java.lang.NullPointerException 
org.forgerock.openidm.quartz.impl.ExecutionException: 
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.forgerock.openidm.provisioner.impl.SystemObjectSetService.execute(SystemObjectSetService.java:280) at org.forgerock.openidm.quartz.impl.SchedulerServiceJob.execute(SchedulerServiceJob.java:127) at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216) at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.forgerock.openidm.provisioner.impl.SystemObjectSetService.liveSync(SystemObjectSetService.java:327) at org.forgerock.openidm.provisioner.impl.SystemObjectSetService.execute(SystemObjectSetService.java:273) ... 3 more
```

The actual error looks like this
[Actual error in command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM6iR.jpg)